# wrap() method doesn't seem to work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

```js
$('input.text-1').wrap('<span class="textfield-1"></span>');
```

```css
.textfield-1 {
  border: 1px solid #d00;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text text-1" />
```

`Wrap()` doesn't seem to work. I don't see `<span>`s wrapped around input in firebug. If they were wrapped, inputs would be hidden with `display: none`, but they aren't.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the result produced and how is it different from what you expected?

Comment: I don't see <span>'s wrapped around input in firebug. If they were indeed wrapped, inputs would be hidden with display:none, but they aren't.

Comment: Code works fine.  Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Does it wrap them correctly if you use .wrap('<span></span>') without classes?

Comment: Another idea: do a console.log('MARK') right before the .wrap line, if it doesn't output MARK in firebug's console your code is failing before that line.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me in Firefox. I recommend that you check there isn't some other code affecting this. Are you sure the wrap method is actually called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works ok for me.  Is it possible that you have a javascript error on the page that is preventing the code from executing?

Here's my test.   Element does become invisible and I can see that it is wrapped in the span.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.textfield-1 {
    border: 1px solid #d00;
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(function(){
            $('input.text-1').wrap('<span class="textfield-1"></span>');
     });


</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="text text-1" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah yes, another function had "&amp;&amp;" instead of &&. Thanks anyway! :)